# Switching between two overlays in leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to have an optional overlay above map that switches between two different WMS layers in leaflet.js if a certain map is selected (if layerX is turned on in LayerControl, layer1 is to be replaced by layer2, and when (Tile)layerX is no longer selected, replace layer2 by layer1 again), so i have listener on overlayadd and overlayremove (

```
map.on('overlayadd', function(layer){if(layer.name === "layerX"){
    layers_on = !!map.hasLayer(layer1);
    layer1.remove();
    layer_selector.removeLayer(layer1);
    if(layers_on){map.addLayer(layer2);
    layer_selector.addOverlay(layer2, "layer2");
}});
map.on('overlayremove', function(layer){if(layer.name === "layerX"){
    layers_on = !!map.hasLayer(layer2);
    layer2.remove();
    layer_selector.removeLayer(layer2);
    if(layers_on){map.addLayer(layer1);}
    layer_selector.addOverlay(layer1, "layer1");
}});
```

Code works fine when switching LayerX on, however when I remove it with layer2 on, it doesn't actually remove it, just replaces it in layer_control and adds layer1 on top of it

Simply said I need a overlay in LayerControl that dynamically shows one of two maps, if LayerX in on then show Layer1 in other case show Layer2. (and the layer itself is optional)

Comment: Perhaps interesting is that the layer no longer appers when you read all layers with map.eachLayer
And it may have something to do with rendering transparent layers, as both layer1 and 2 are transparent

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate a `L.Control.Layers`, and add your two `L.TileLayer.WMS`s as "base layers" in that control.

The name might be deceiving: what it means is that, for a given `L.Control.Layers`, the layers passed as "base layers" are mutually exclusive. They do nto need to be thematically base layers, and you can have more than one `L.Control.Layers` with a set of mutually exclusive `L.Layer`s in each.

Comment: Although that sort of works, it just isn't the same functionality. The whole point of the code is to have two actual wmts maps on top of each other since one only covers Czech Republic. Then layer1 and layer2 - while exclusive - have the same map, one is just negative of the other, the point was to have just one button for this overlay

Comment: and they are also optional, which the base layer part of L.Control.Layers doesn't allow

Comment: If the point is to have *one button*, then please edit your question to reflect so. Your question as written does not constraint the UI.

Comment: Hopefully it's better discribed now, I don't think the problem is necessarily with the code itself (There probably is a better solution but I can't think of one), but although the code is basically the same both ways, it doesn't work that way and leaves layer2 on the map, even though I call layer2.remove();